# Recognize some 4-dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-decomposition

I am looking for the matrix representations of the Lie Algebra given by the commutators:

$[G_1,G_2]=0,\\ [G_1,G_3]=-[G_2,G_3]=G_4,\\ [G_1,G_4]=G_3, [G_2,G_4]=-G_3,\\ [G_3,G_4]=-2G_1+2G_2$

But I don't know if they form some well-known Lie Algebra.

Comment: What is the ring of coefficients?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the term 'ring of coefficients'. I'm new to Lie algebra.

Comment: It is an algebra over what? Complex numbers, real numbers, integers, rational numbers?

Comment: I think complex numbers. It's either real or complex but definitely not just integers or rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo. We need $[G_2,G_4]=-G_3$ and not $+G_3$. Otherwise the Jacobi identity is not satisfied:
$$
[G_1,[G_2,G_3]]+[G_2,[G_3,G_1]]+[G_3,[G_1,G_2]]=-G_3-G_3+0\neq 0.
$$

For all real and complex Lie Algebras of dimension $4$,  *faithful* matrix representations of minimal degree have been determined. See for example the paper by Ghanam and Thompson "Minimal Matrix Representations of Four-Dimensional Lie Algebras".

For a general method to compute this, at least for nilpotent Lie algebras, see my paper [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_35_nilrep.pdf).

It is easy to find out which algebra from the list is yours in dimension $4$ by comparing isomorphism invariants, like $\dim [L,L]$, or $\dim Z(L)$ or
$\dim [[L,L],[L,L]]$ or $\dim \operatorname{Der}(L)$, etc.

So your Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\oplus \Bbb C=\mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C)$, where the center is generated by $2(G_2-G_1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the typo in the question.

Comment: I don't understand the meanings of $dim[L, L]$, etc. Sorry, but can you elaborate on what am I looking for to identify my Lie algebra?

Comment: The commutator subalgebra of $L$ is denoted by $[L,L]$. This is a vector space, and hence has a dimension. If the Lie algebra is abelian then it is the zero space.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but could you show me how to do it for my particular example of the Lie algebra, if it is ok?   I

Comment: I have here: $\\ [G_k,G_k]=[G_1,G_2]=0\\ [G_1,G_3]=[G_3,G_2]=G_4\\ [G_1,G_4] = [G_4,G_2] = G_3\\ [G_3,G_4] = -2G_1+2G_2.\\ $         So is that $dim[L,L]=4$?

Comment: No, the space is spanned by three vectors only, namely $G_3,G_4,-2G_1+2G_2$, so it cannot have dimension $4$, right?

Comment: Ok, got it. So now in the next step should I go through the list and check which algebra has $dim[L,L]=3?$ And also, to find out $dim([L,L],[L,L])$ I have $[G_3,G_4]=-2G_1+2G_2\\ [G_3, -2G_1+2G_2]=4 G_4\\ [G_4, -2G_1+2G_2]=4G_3$. So that gives me $dim=3$ again?

Comment: Yes, very good. It is useful to know that a $3$-dimensional complex Lie algebra $L$ with $L=[L,L]$ must be simple, namely isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$. So your commutator subalgebra is simple. Hence your Lie algebra must be $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\oplus \Bbb C=\mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb C)$, where the center is generated by $2(G_2-G_1)$.

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I get to the matrix representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ for my generators?

Comment: Just take the adjoint representation (but it is not faithful here, since we have a nontrivial center).

Comment: What is an adjoint representation?

Comment: See [adjoint representation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjointRepresentation.html).

Answer (score 1):

The list of all 4-dim **real** Lie algebras can be found here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_low-dimensional_real_Lie_algebras

Comment: Thank you. I don't see my commutators in this list so is there another way I can find the matrix representations.

Comment: Read the article. All commutators which are not present are 0. The first description was published in 1963 in Russian but a more detailed description was published in 2003 in English.There is a standard way to describe a linear representation of a finite dim Lie algebra, using Lie groups.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but is there a more, beginner-level introduction on this topic.

Comment: What topic? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Going from Lie Algebra to their matrix representations. So basically I know the structure constants using one particular basis. I don't know how to match them to the list of well-known ones. They look different if they chose a different basis from me.

Comment: First you need to find your Lie algebra on the list. It must be there because rhe list is complete.

Comment: I don't know to how look for it. Just by comparing the commutators, I am unable to find a match.