# What are the generators of $\mathfrak{gl}_2(\mathbb{C})=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\oplus\mathbb{C}$ and their matrix representations?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$[G_1,G_2]=0,\\ [G_1,G_3]=-[G_2,G_3]=G_4,\\ [G_1,G_4]=G_3, [G_2,G_4]=-G_3,\\ [G_3,G_4]=-2G_1+2G_2$

These form the said Lie algebra but how do I find their matrix representations?

Comment: Take the adjoint representation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795328/what-are-some-common-4-generator-lie-algebras). More generally, use the representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
G_1 &= \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
G_2 &= \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\
G_3 &= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
G_4 &= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

I found this by using the standard basis
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h_1 &= \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
h_2 &= \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\
e &= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
f &= \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
Computing commutators, it's not much thought after that

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the standard basis and how did you pick them/use them?

Comment: For sure. So $\mathfrak {gl}_n\mathbb C$ is the space of $n\times n$ complex matrices, and this has a simple linear basis given by $E_{ij}$, which is zero everywhere except at row $i$ and column $j$, where it is $1$.

Comment: It is a useful exercise to compute the commutator $[E_{ij}, E_{lm}]$ for generic $i, j, l, m\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: In the decomposition $\mathfrak {gl}_n=\mathfrak {sl}_n\oplus\mathbb C$, the $\mathbb C$ corresponds to the identity element $\sum_{i=1}^nE_{ii}$, which commutes with everything.